# javascript: Checking if tags are next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, tags

So here is the problem: I want to check if element `<x-statement>` is right next to `<p>` and there is no text in between them.
So this will return true:

```
<div>
     <x-statement>[discover.prev]</x-statement>
     <p>Go forward<p>
</div>
```

But this won't:

```
<div>
     <x-statement>[discover.prev]</x-statement>
     im in the way herr der
     <p>Go forward<p>
</div>
```

This what I've tried to do:

```
if($(this).next().is('p')){
    alert("p is next to you");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: `x-statement` is not a valid tagName

Comment: `document.querySelector('x-statement').nextSibling.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'p';`

Comment: @user3731759 Be aware that adeneo's code may not work in browsers where `nextSibling` considers whitespace-only text nodes to be siblings. Which is most of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more robust function using DOM methods

```
function nextIs(self, tag) {
    return self ? ((function(el) {
        while(el && el.nodeValue && el.nodeValue.trim() == '' ) el = el.nextSibling
        return el;
    })(self.nextSibling).tagName || '').toLowerCase() === tag : false;
}
```

can be used as

```
var element = document.querySelector('x-statement');
var isNextP = nextIs(, 'p');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WMcF5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1">
     <x-statement>[discover.prev]</x-statement>
     <p>Go forward<p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
     <x-statement>[discover.prev]</x-statement>
     im in the way herr der
     <p>Go forward<p>
</div>

var exp = /<x-statement>.*<\/x-statement>\s*\n*<p>.*<\/p>/;
alert(exp.test($("#div1").html()));
alert(exp.test($("#div2").html()));
```

Example on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PL9pN/